# Category page not working Magento 2 with more than 13 million products

Tags: mysql, performance, magento, magento2

I am stuck in an issue with Magento 2 has more than 13 million products. We have managed to upload 13 million products although is slow and it works like indexing, product page, and search page.
[image]

My frontend category page isn't opening now after waiting almost 2 minutes getting memory exhausted we have tried to allocate 18GB memory but it gets stuck on this query and through error memory exhausted.

```
SELECT  1 AS status, e.entity_id, e.attribute_set_id, e.type_id,
        e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.sku,
        cat_index.position AS cat_index_position,
        stock_status_index.stock_status AS is_salable
    FROM  catalog_product_flat_1 AS e
    INNER JOIN  catalog_category_product_index_store1 AS cat_index
           ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
      AND  cat_index.store_id=1
      AND  cat_index.category_id='4'
    INNER JOIN  cataloginventory_stock_status AS stock_status_index
           ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id
      AND  stock_status_index.website_id = 0
      AND  stock_status_index.stock_id = 1
    WHERE  (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)
```

Can anyone please suggest me how can I overcome this issue or speed up the processes and MySQL queries what architecture level changes should I do to make it work the category list page on frontend. I know this is huge data but it's our requirement to have this much products. We have a pretty good server

- Intel Xeon E5-2689v4
- 128 GB RAM
- 1200 GB Datastores

  I have already enabled flat catalog product and flat catalog category both.

Comment: have you enabled flat catalog product and flat catalog category ? Which mode you have enabled ?

Comment: yes both are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Add these composite indexes:

```
stock_status_index:  (stock_status, website_id, stock_id, product_id)
e:  (entity_id)  -- unless that is the PRIMARY KEY
cat_index:  (product_id, store_id, category_id)
```

If those do not help enough, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

More indexing tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql